# Change annotation background colors in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, colors, background, annotations

So in eclipse whenever there is an error it's underlined in red, and when you hover over it is displays an annotation with tips on how to fix the error.  On my Windows OS it is correct and the background is a tanish color but on Ubuntu the background is black and I want it tanish like Windows.  I know there is an annotation area under Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations, but I don't see a section to change background colors. Please help.

Comment: Any luck? I would love to be able to change this!

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, colors and fonts are very poorly implemented in Eclipse.  Quite a number of things are either extremely difficult to figure out or impossible.  Looks like this one is impossible to modify.  Perhaps there's an OS way to make those changes?

That said, I found an Eclipse plugin, Annotions Ruler Background.  It looks like it should do the trick, but was designed for Indigo (3.7) and doesn't seem to work on Juno (4.2). Sigh.

You can install it from the usual way in Eclipse (help->eclipse marketplace->search, etc.).  Their website is [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/99539#.UK1G_XC8yUg).

If you're still on Indigo, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I find this page, it works. http://ubuntu-user-tricks.blogspot.tw/2012/09/3-things-to-do-after-installing-eclipse.html

It change the theme tooltip background color, and foreground color if need.

You can install tool **gnome-color-chooser** or modify the configure directly (default at **/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc**). If  After you modify the theme configure, you need reload theme to use new config.